# Two scrollable content bars with fixed header and footer

Tags: html, css

I have this code with the reqirement to add another side menu to my existing page

https://jsfiddle.net/84j7wcqa/

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <div class="inner">header</div>
</div>
<div class="top">
    <div class="inner">top</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="right">
            <div style="height:1000px;">right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="inner">footer</div>
</div>
```

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.header, .content, .footer, .top {
    display: table-row;
}

.header, .footer {
    background: silver;
}

.inner {
    display: table-cell;
}

.content .inner {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.top {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

which looks this way:

[image]

But I want a additional content which is scrollable to look it like this

[image]

Question: Can this be solved with the `table` / `table-row` / `table-cell` approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my answer in this link. Hope this helps.
https://jsfiddle.net/m2vpcs1u/3/

HTML:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="inner">header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="top">
        <div class="inner">top</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="right">
                <div style="height:1000px;">right</div>
            </div>
             <div class="left">
                <div style="height:1000px;">left</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="inner">footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.header, .content, .footer, .top {
    display: table-row;
}

.header, .footer {
    background: silver;
}

.inner {
    display: table-cell;
}

.content .inner {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width:50%;
}
.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width:50%;
}


.top {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```css
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .wrapper {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            display: table;
        }
        .header, .content, .footer, .top {
            display: table-row;
        }
        .header, .footer {
            background: silver;
        }
        .inner {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .inner .left {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
            overflow: auto;
            height: 900px;
        }
        .inner .right {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
            overflow: auto;
            height: 900px;
        }
        .content .inner {
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            background: pink;
        }
        .top {
            background-color: gold;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="inner">header</div>
        </div>
        <div class="top">
            <div class="inner">top</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="left">
                    <div style="height:1000px;">left</div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <div style="height:1000px;">right</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="inner">footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: good approach but the footer is gone - is there a way to maintain this?